# Comparing large numbers of files in Bash quickly

Tags: bash

I downloaded many files (~10,000) from a website, most of which are a bunch of useless html that all say the same thing.  However, there are some files in this haystack that have useful information (and are thus fairly different files) and I need a quick way to separate those from the rest.  I know I can go through all of the files one by one and use cmp to compare to a template and see if they are the same, and the delete them.  However, this is rather slow.  Is there a faster way to do this?  I don't mind if I only have a 99% recovery rate.

Comment: To be clear: you want to delete all the files whose contents matches that of a specified template file?

Comment: You could do to be more specific in your question. Do you mean the majority of the files are identical, i.e. the content matches byte for byte from beginning to end? Or simply that they're similar? What do you mean when you say some files are "thus fairly different files"? They differ in content? File type? Size? Something else?

Comment: Yes, I would like to delete the files that match, they are all exactly the same, byte for byte. The different files have additional info, and thus would be larger, but would be the same file type.

Comment: If the important files have a different size, just `ls -lS` and then delete the files with the same size (you can select them with `grep`, but be careful if your filenames contain spaces).

Comment: @choroba I have way too many files to select them all separately ~500.  Would there be a way to do this simply using Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one lists the unique files in the tree passed as the argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A uniques
while IFS= read -r file; do
    [[ ! "${uniques[${file%% *}]}" ]] && uniques[${file%% *}]="${file##* }"
done< <(find "$1" -type f -exec md5sum -b "{}" \;)

for file in ${uniques[@]}; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Many thanks to triplee for the better approach using md5sum!

Previous version:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a files uniques

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    files[${#files[@]}]="$file"
done< <(find "$1" -type f -print0)

uniques=( ${files[@]} )
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    for unique in "${!uniques[@]}"; do
        [[ "$file" != "${uniques[$unique]}" ]] && cmp -s "$file" "${uniques[$unique]}" && && unset -v uniques[$unique]
    done
done

for unique in "${uniques[@]}"; do
    echo "$unique"
done
```

Comment: This will perform a massive amount of redundant comparisons. Run `md5sum` on your files and select the unique ones instead.

Comment: @triplee: You're right, that's much much better. I'll update the code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the files are in or below the current directory, and the template is in the parent directory, and the filenames have no spaces:

```
find . -type f -print | while read -r filename; do
  if ! cmp --quiet $filename ../template; then
    echo rm $filename
  fi
done
```

remove the "echo" if you're satisfied this works.